# How to get only one specific line from subprocess output

Tags: python, subprocess

I know how to search if specific word exists in subprocess output. But how can I print out only one specific line, if I know this line always looks like:

```
This is the line:    some text
```

"Some text" can have different values.

What I have:

```
variable = subprocess.call(["some", "command"], stdout=subprocess.PIPE, stderr=subprocess.PIPE)
stdout, stderr = output.communicate()
```

What I want to get after executing the script:

```
This is the line:    some text
```

Comment: iterate over and use `if line.startswith("This is the line:")`

Comment: use `for line in subprocess.check_output(["some", "command"]).splitlines():` to get the output

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
import subprocess
p = subprocess.Popen(["some", "command"], stdout=subprocess.PIPE, stderr=subprocess.PIPE)
stdout, stderr = p.communicate()
stdout=stdout.split("\n")
for line in stdout:
    if line.startswith("This is the line:"):
        print line
```